# Formatting psql output (number of digits) via postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, number-formatting

This seems like the sort of question that would have an answer on SO, but I can't find it anywhere.

I want to set the default number of digits displayed on a query.

Say I have a table, taxes_table, with lots of column of type `numeric`.

I want

```
select * from taxes_table;
```

To display each element only up to, say, the second digit. I don't want to have to trunc or round every element.

Comment: What about using precision `NUMERIC(precision, scale)` ? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: Thanks, but assume I don't have control of the data warehouse. I don't want to change all the datatypes, I just want to truncate the result of every query to no-more-than-two-significant-digits.